What's this movie with a psycho couple and zombies / cannibals in the basement?
I remember watching a half movie in early 2000s on HBO. I forgot it's name and actors, but it was an english movie.
In general, it was a story about a psycho couple living in a big house and having millions on dollars, and zombie-like cannibals imprisoned in the basement.
Story was about a man (black) that goes into a big house for robbery with a teenager (prolly his son) and tries to look around. Then they found out that house owner and his wife came home and have a shotgun. The man hides in the closet and lets the boy die. But all of a sudden (I don't remember what happens), the house owner (psychopath) found the black dude and shot him and then later serves the dead man's hand (cooked) to his pet dog.
I also remember one scene where there were a lot of hungry prisoners in the basement of house and they were trying to kill the wandering boy. And he found out that the owners (couple) are psychopaths, and he also found a girl in that house who became friends with them.
Please help me find it.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

This sounds like The People Under the Stairs, a Wes Craven film from 1991.  From IMDB: "The People Under the Stairs is the story of a young boy (Fool) from the ghetto and takes place on his 13th birthday. In an attempted burglary (along with two others) of the home of his family's evil landlords, he becomes trapped inside their large suburban house and discovers the secret of the "children" that the insane brother and sister have been "rearing" under the stairs."

Thanks! you're right SirJonSnow,I was 8 when I saw it... don't remember the exact plot.. I'll watch it again...
